# Byte testing c#

Tags: c#, byte

I have a data acquisition module.
It return a byte for each bit is 1.

Example :
- Byte : 9
- 0000 1001

And I would like to know how see if each bit is 1.

Someone tell me to do " 9 & 1 " in order to see if the first bit is 1 but it don't work. Or I don't use it well.

```
for(int i = 1; i<=5 ;i ++)
{
    if((portData2 & i) == 1)
    {
        switch(i)
        {
            case 1:
                IN0D.Text = 1.ToString();
                break;
            case 2:
                IN1D.Text = 1.ToString();
                break;
            case 3:
                IN2D.Text = 1.ToString();
                break;
            case 4:
                IN3D.Text = 1.ToString();
                break;
            case 5:
                IN4D.Text = 1.ToString();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you mixed up Bits and Bytes. Bytes range from 0 to 255 and contain 8 Bits...

Comment: You confuse "Bit" and "Byte". We say a "Bit is set" or "a Bit is 1 or 0". Not "on 1".

Comment: Read about "Byte" and "Bit" and logical bitwise operations.

Comment: Ohhh yea, thank you. Ok I go read about this

Comment: What doesn't work? Please post the code you used. Doing a bitwise-AND *is* how bit values are checked

Comment: See my answer on why testing bit 5 as `& 5` is wrong.

Comment: I vote to reopen - I think that especially after seeing the source code it is pretty obvious what's going wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To test whether a bit is set in a byte, you use the `&` operator like this:

```
if ((b & 1) > 0)
{
    // Bit 0 is set
}
if ((b & 2) > 0)
{
    // Bit 1 is set
}
if ((b & 4) > 0)
{
    // Bit 2 is set
}
```

and so forth.

Please note this:

```
Bit to test:    7   6   5   4   3   2   1   0
Value for &:  128  64  32  16   8   4   2   1
```

You will notice that the value to `&` is always `2 ^ x`, with `x` being the index of the bit you want to check, which you can write as `1 << x` in C#. So the following extension method could test an arbitrary bit within a byte:

```
public static bool IsBitSet(this byte b, int bitIndex)
{
    if (bitIndex < 0 || bitIndex > 7)
        throw new ArgumentException("bitIndex must be between 0 and 7!");

    var bit = 1 << bitIndex;
    return (b & bit) > 0;
}
```

---

Keeping in mind the above, you could rewrite your code like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    if ((portData2 & (1 << i)) > 0)
    {
        switch(i)
        {
            case 0:
                IN0D.Text = "1";
                break;
            case 1:
                IN1D.Text = "1";
                break;
            case 2:
                IN2D.Text = "1";
                break;
            case 3:
                IN3D.Text = "1";
                break;
            case 4:
                IN4D.Text = "1";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Or using my above extension method without a loop as:

```
IN0D.Text = portData2.IsBitSet(0) ? "1" : "0";
IN1D.Text = portData2.IsBitSet(1) ? "1" : "0";
IN2D.Text = portData2.IsBitSet(2) ? "1" : "0";
IN3D.Text = portData2.IsBitSet(3) ? "1" : "0";
IN4D.Text = portData2.IsBitSet(4) ? "1" : "0";
```

Please note that `1.ToString()` is simply `"1"`. Why make things complicated?

Comment: Some people name the _lowest significant bit_ as "Bit 0"